# Node.js / Knowing if ReadStream.pipe is transfer a data

Tags: node.js, stream

I try to find a way to check if a pipe is freezes or data is still piping. I have the following code:

```
var downloadStream1 = download1.createReadStream();
var pipeOfDownloadClient = downloadStream1.pipe(response);
```

I try to find an event like this:

```
pipeOfDownloadClient.on('data', function(data){
      logger.info("Data is piping");
})
```

But when I did this, no `data is piping` was printed, although data was transferred to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just check `downloadStream1`'s `data` event. It will tell you exactly whether or not its `.pipe` is still emitting data.

If you check `pipeOfDownloadClient._events` it would only have these 3 events: `drain`, `error`, and `close`. No `data` event.